# Send jquery variable from view to joomla 2.5 controller using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, joomla

I have the following on `com_show/views/tmpl/default.php`:

```
function CategoryItems(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        var ids = this.id;          
        var u = "<?php echo JURI::root();?>index.php?option=com_show&controller=names&task=showName&id=" + ids;          
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            type:'GET', 
            url: u,
            data: { id: ids },  
            success: function(data) { }                                                     
        }); //end of ajax
    });
    return false;
}
```

And on controller I have the following:

```
function showName(){
    $myid = JRequest::getVar('id', 'no value');  
    return $myid;
}
```

The problem is on ajax part.  When I try getting the returned value from function '`showName()`' in controller 'name', Am always getting 'no value' instead of the id.

Kindly assist,

Comment: I guess that all buttons have ids, yes? I don't know much about Joomla on server side but notice that you are duplicating the 'id' query parameter because you write it on the URL and also pass it as a 'data' parameter to Jquery AJAX

Comment: Yes all buttons have ids. I removed the id duplicate. First from url and then from the data parameter but still didn't work out for me